# How do i load a plugin class with Java?

Tags: java, plugins, casting, classloader

I made a small application that loads classes from a folder, displays them in a list and when you click on one it displays the `JPanel` in it.

So i made an API class (`BaseApp`) which extends `JPanel`. I also made a test class which `extends BaseApp` and uses the APIs in it.

Now, my problem is that every time i click on `TestApp`, it gives me this `Exception`...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class     cannot be cast to me.Delocaz.SuperApp.BaseApp
at me.Delocaz.SuperApp.AppSelect$2.mouseClicked(AppSelect.java:76)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried to cast the `Class` i got from my classloader into a `BaseApp`. How do i do that without it crashing?

If you need it, here's my `FileClassLoader`:

```
package me.Delocaz.SuperApp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class FileClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public Class<?> findClass(File f) {
        byte[] b = loadClassData(f);
        try {
        return defineClass(null, b, 0, b.length);
        } catch (ClassFormatError ex) {
        return null;
        }
    }
    private byte[] loadClassData(File f) {
        FileInputStream fin;
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            fin.read(fileContent);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileContent;
    }
}
```

Also, this is where the casting occurs:

```
Object c = cl.findClass(new File(***CLASS FILE LOCATION***));
System.out.println(c);
switchApp((BaseApp) c);
```

Answer (score 2):

An instance of type `Class` is not an instance of type `BaseApp`, so the conversion fails.  You need to instantiate the class to get an instance of type `BaseClass`, which you can then cast

Try calling `newInstance()` on the class instance to get a new instance of the loaded class (based on its default constructor)

Comment: Your comment _is_ a reply.  Please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem